# I am not able to publish SNS messages as email

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am using the following code:

```
 AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(credentials);
 snsClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.SA_EAST_1));
                    String msg = "My text published to SNS topic with email endpoint";
                    String arn = "XXXXX";
                    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest("topicARN here",msg);
                    PublishResult publishResult = snsClient.publish(publishRequest);
```

But I am getting Following ERROR.

> "InvalidParameterException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonSNS,
>   AWS Request ID: 446fef49-4eba-5484-ba4c-bf82682cdc46, AWS Error Code:
>   InvalidParameter, AWS Error Message: Invalid parameter: TopicArn"

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your topic ARN does not exist yet. Check that it exists or create it explicitly.

Here'a `HelloWorldSNS` for you:

```
public class HelloWorldSNS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        AmazonSNSClient client = Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).createClient(AmazonSNSClient.class, null,
                null);
        CreateTopicResult createTopic = client.createTopic("myTopic");
        SubscribeResult subscribe = client.subscribe(createTopic.getTopicArn(), "email", "some@email.com");
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(createTopic.getTopicArn(), "Test message");
        client.publish(publishRequest);
    }
}
```